# Expo - Build android app-bundle with "app signing" certificates

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo

I have an already **published** (to Google Play) **APK** that was built by **Expo**.
The key was also created by Expo. Until now everything works great.

I tried to build an app-bundle because now it is the recommended way to build apps for **Android**. It also helps to reduce app size.

I followed [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/app-signing/) documentation (that is not 100% clear).
I ran `expo opt-in-google-play-signing` and followed the instructions.
Eventually the certificates in Google Console were created **successfully**.

In **Release Management > App Signing** it now says "App signing by Google Play is enabled for this app".

But it looks like those certificates **were not** successfully uploaded to Expo (I am not sure if this is the problem).

I am building the app-bundle with this command: `expo build:android -t app-bundle`.

But the problem is when I am trying to upload the app-bundle in the **Release Management** in the console it says that the app is signed with a wrong upload certificate.

I tried everything that I was able to find in the searches but nothing helped.

I am completely lost. Can someone please instruct me how I can correctly build the app-bundle and successfully upload it to Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@danigonlinea/how-to-sign-your-expo-app-by-google-play-successfully-b591471538cb) to describe the steps you need to follow. What it is important is that you, once you create the certificates in Google Play, use the MD5 as password for your upload key and your store key.